# Error: Uncaught (in promise): plugin_not_installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, promise, ionic3

So, I'm reading the next [tutorial](https://alligator.io/ionic/intro-slider/) and when I run the app on my device immediately the next error is shown:

[image: screenshot]

Which plugin is not installed?

[image: plugins]

Those are the plugins I've installed, and the package.json.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Install cordova for browser or run a check before using a plugin to see if cordova is present:

```
if (this.Platform.is('cordova')) {
//run code with cordova plugin
} else {
//ignore plugin
}
```